# Async code inside of a test works but shows not run

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await

I have a test that I'm having trouble with. It needs to execute async code, but it needs to properly succeed/fail. Based on my research, building an async test won't actually fail properly, so I tried something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyAsynchronousSend()
{
    Task.Run(() => this.asbMessagingClient.SendAsync(new MessageInfo
    {
        Message = $"{MessageBody} async",
        AppId = AppId,
        Filter = Filter
    })).Wait();
}
```

The message does get written to the ASB, and does succeed, but it shows as **not run** in the test explorer. Can somebody help me structure this properly?

Here is the code its executing:

```
public async Task SendAsync(MessageInfo messageInfo)
{
    var asbMessage = ConstructMessage(messageInfo);

    this.logger.WriteInfo($"ASB: Sending message async. {messageInfo} Message ID: {asbMessage.MessageId};");

    await this.TopicClient.SendAsync(asbMessage);
}
```

Comment: `Based on my research, building an async test won't actually fail properly` - what research?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to use `await` inside of your unit tests and mark your test methods as `async` provided you return a `Task` object. In fact the article shared in the question does have few unit tests written with `async/await`.What the articles says is to avoid `async void`, in which case any exceptions thrown will be ignored and might result in improper test results.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task VerifyAsynchronousSend()
{
    await this.asbMessagingClient.SendAsync(new MessageInfo
    {
        Message = $"{MessageBody} async",
        AppId = AppId,
        Filter = Filter
    });

    //Assert
}
```

Another [good article](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/) which talks about avoiding async void in unit tests.

Comment: That code actually produces the same result, where it "works", but the test shows not run.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "where it works". And does your unit test have at least one assert?

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous code should be run asynchronously:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task VerifyAsynchronousSend()
{
    await this.asbMessagingClient.SendAsync(new MessageInfo
    {
        Message = $"{MessageBody} async",
        AppId = AppId,
        Filter = Filter
    };

    Assert.Inconclusiev();
}
```

[Async Programming : Unit Testing Asynchronous Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/november/async-programming-unit-testing-asynchronous-code)

Comment: That code actually produces the same result, where it "works", but the test shows not run.

Comment: It doesn't show that. It just doesn't show a result because you haven't provided one. I changed the test to publish an inconclusive result.

Answer (score -3):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void VerifyAsynchronousSend()
    {
        var result = this.asbMessagingClient.SendAsync(new MessageInfo
        {
            Message = $"{MessageBody} async",
            AppId = AppId,
            Filter = Filter
        })).Result;

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

Comment: .Result will give a wrapped exception, if any. .GetAwaiter().GetResult() should be used when doing stuff like you suggest. In this case, I can't see why OP can't use a plain await.

Comment: It will give a warning as await is used only with async method. Also there is no purpose in having an asynchronous test case.

Comment: Well, when you're testing async stuff, then an async unit test method will be inevitable.

Comment: @RoarS. there is a lot of guidance around *not* building `async` tests. Here is an entire write up by Microsoft, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/november/async-programming-unit-testing-asynchronous-code, and I can find more.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud: "Most modern unit test frameworks support Task-returning asynchronous unit tests". I can't see why we should disagree?

Comment: @MikePerrenoud That doesn't say you shouldn't have asynchronous tests, it just says that they shouldn't be async void test methods, which of course is correct, you shouldn't do that.  It shows how to test an asynchronous method correctly in that article.  Notice that the solution it says is correct is not to block on the task synchronously, like you're doing.